# Join 2 rows in same table sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Hi have a query that produces the following result?

```
  name                       count    
  19 - Evening ACL           1130
  21 - 14 - 16 Provision     585
  81 - HE FT                 458
  85 - HE PT                 233
```

How can I get so that the query joins the two rows contains 'HE'. The result I am after is:

```
  name                    count
  19 - Evening ACL        1130
  21 - 14 - 16 Provision  585
  HE                      691
```

Here is the query I am using

```
SELECT 
vc.vc_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT s.s_studentreference) AS 'Count'

FROM

student s
INNER JOIN person p ON p.p_id = s.s_id
INNER JOIN moduleenrolment e ON e.e_student = p.p_id
INNER JOIN module m ON m.m_id = e.e_module
LEFT JOIN valid_codes vc ON vc.vc_code = m.m_mode AND vc.vc_domain = 'moa'

WHERE

LEFT(m.m_reference, 2) IN ('12')


GROUP BY

m.m_mode,
vc.vc_name

ORDER BY

m.m_mode,
vc.vc_name
```

Thanks

Comment: how many rows do you have? what are their names?

Comment: In total there are 18 rows the section of code above is just a sample, there are two columns, one called name and the other is a Count

Comment: sorry, I mean columns. I was thinking of columns but i wrote rows. Can you label the sample data?

Comment: Make a case statement to pick out rows that contain `HE`, and group by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Assuming `'HE'` has a space on either side);

```
select name, count
from yourTable where charindex(' he ',name)=0
union
select 'HE' name, sum(count) as count
from yourTable where charindex(' he ',name)>0
```

Another way is;

```
select A.name, sum(A.count) as count
from (
    select case charindex(' he ',name) 
           when 0 then name else 'HE' end name, count
    from yourTable
) A
group by A.name
order by A.name
```

Answer (score 1):

the column "name" in the original resultset 
is just a column or its a computed column build by concatenating data?

using the force(like a jedi), I would say that it seems to be concatenating the numbers with the description and the letters PT, FT...

if this is the case.. u must to identify in group clause what is diferent in the two rows that contain the HE description... I bet the collumn that give the letters "P" and "F" on the first result are in the group clause... so you should cut off them from the group by.. and see how concat them... (in mySQL have the command GROUP_CONCAT(), but in sqlserver i guess still dont have a native function to do that, but have many techniques to get this result)

but in this way you would get the line

> 81 - 85 HE PFT                 691

if you post the query of the first resultset would help to understand better your problem to give a solution

anyway.. if this is not the case I dont understand why you should want to agregate those two lines in one.. but the only solution would identify which names has the 'HE' like Kaf solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited the post with the query I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another column, a computed column with the information you want to join on - i.e. extract that information (HE for your sample) in a separate column.

If you have very many rows consider creating a view and adding an index on that column (thus materializing the view) to speed up the join.